# How do I unit test this JavaScript function, including mocking of Ajax call?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, unit-testing, mocking, qunit

As seen in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aknuds1/bCNcj), I have a function 'init' that configures a button so that when clicked it opens a progress dialog and issues an Ajax call. I want to unit test this JavaScript code (using [QUnit](http://qunitjs.com/)), and check the following cases:

1. Ajax call succeeds
2. Ajax call fails

I need to mock out at least the Ajax call and the call to `window.open`, and other calls I'm sure, depending on unit test implementation.

How can I write QUnit unit tests for my code that tests these two scenarios?

**EDIT:** The code that needs to be tested:

```
var statusmod = (function() {
    var spinner = $("#spinner");

    var init = function(id) {
        var progressDialog = $("#progressdialog-content").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: "Launching Status Page"
        });
        var errorDialog = $("#errordialog-content").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "OK": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });

        var btn = $("#button-status");
        btn.button().click(function() {
            spinner.show();

            progressDialog.dialog("open");

            var url = $.validator.format("/api/binid/?id={0}", id);
            // Call Web service to get binary ID
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                dataType: "json"
            }).done(function(data) {
                window.open($.validator.format("http://status/?Page=Status&Id={0}", data.Id), target = "_newtab");
            }).fail(function(jqXHR, msg, errorThrown) {
                errorDialog.dialog("open");
            }).always(function() {
                progressDialog.dialog("close");
            });

            return false;
        });
    };

    return {
        init: init,
        _spinner: spinner
    };
}());
```

Comment: Consider mockjax for mocking the ajax call, works like a charm

Comment: @rsplak Could you please show how to run tests after Ajax callbacks have been invoked? Can't see how, at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have successfully written a QUnit test for the success case and another for the failure case, as you can see from [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aknuds1/Ph8qH/15/). I employed [Mockjax](https://github.com/appendto/jquery-mockjax) to fake Ajax responses and simulate success/failure conditions. Notably, I configured Ajax calls to be synchronous, so that I could write synchronous tests, as I had trouble figuring out how to run my tests after asynchronous Ajax callbacks had fired.

I also make use of the [Sinon.JS](http://sinonjs.org/) library to fake dependencies and verify that e.g. dialogs are launched correctly.

The working test code is included below, see my question for the function under test (`statusmod.init`). Let me know if there's something you think I've left out.

```
var dialogSpy = null;
var windowSpy = null;
var id = "srcId";
var binId = "binId";
var url = $.validator.format("/api/binid/?id={0}", id);
var btnId = "#button-status";

module("Open status page", {
    setup: function() {
        // Allow us to run tests synchronously
        $.ajaxSetup({
            async: false
        });
        windowSpy = sinon.spy(window, "open");
        dialogSpy = sinon.spy();
        sinon.stub($.fn, "dialog", function() {
            return {
                "dialog": dialogSpy
            };
        });

        statusmod.init(id);
    },
    teardown: function() {
        windowSpy.restore();
        $.fn.dialog.restore();
        $.mockjaxClear();
        // Remove click event handler for each test
        $(btnId).unbind();
    }
});

test("Successfully open status page", function() {
    expect(4);

    $.mockjax({
        url: url,
        contentType: "text/json",
        responseText: {
            Id: binId
        }
    });

    var spinner = statusmod._spinner;
    var spinnerSpy = sinon.spy(spinner, "show");

    $(btnId).click();

    ok(spinnerSpy.calledOnce, "Spinner shown");
    ok(dialogSpy.withArgs("open").calledOnce, "Dialog opened");
    ok(dialogSpy.withArgs("close").calledOnce, "Dialog closed");
    equal(windowSpy.lastCall.args[0], $.validator.format("http://status/?Page=Status&Id={0}", binId), "Window opened");
});

test("Binary ID not found on server", function() {
    expect(3);

    $.mockjax({
        url: url,
        contentType: "text/json",
        status: 404
    });

    $(btnId).click();

    ok(dialogSpy.withArgs("open").calledTwice, "Dialogs opened");
    ok(dialogSpy.withArgs("close").calledOnce, "Progress dialog closed");
    ok(!windowSpy.called, "Window not launched");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, download and include [Mockjax](https://github.com/appendto/jquery-mockjax).

Then mock your ajax calls:

```
module("Mock Ajax", {
  setup: function () {
    /** this mocks the ajax call **/
    $.mockjax({
      url: 'yourUrl.php',
      data: {'action': 'your',
        'data': {
          'that': 'you',
          'send': 'here'
        }
      },
      responseText:'{"your": ["returned":"json"],"string"}'
    });
  });
});
```

And then you can make your ajax call in a testcase:

```
test( "Your testcase", function() {
  $.ajax('yourUrl.php',
    data: {'action': 'your',
       'data': {
      'that': 'you',
      'send': 'here'
    }
  }, function(data) {
      ok("do something with your data");
  });
});
```

Et voilà, you've succesfully tested something! You can add extra parameters to your mockjax call (isTImeout, isError, etc). Documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/appendto/jquery-mockjax).

These are the basics, you can edit it to suit your needs using the documentation, which is pretty complete.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't really solve my problem. I don't want to make a mock Ajax call in my testcase, I want to call `status.init`, click the button, and ensure that the Ajax call gets made correctly and that the done/fail/always callbacks do the right thing. I have an almost working solution from hacking on the problem today, but am currently stuck at a tiny detail in mockjax.

Comment: On that note, maybe you can answer my specific mockjax question as it should be quite simple? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093731/why-does-mockjax-return-an-altered-response-to-my-ajax-consumer